# How do i translate this into c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, xtrareport

I have found aa solution to a problem in one of my reports but its in VB.NET and I am not sure how to convert it to C#, I tried to do it online with one of the tools but it cant determine the events been used or something like that. If there is anyone savy at both languages maybe you can help me figure out its translation? Here is the VB code

```
Private Sub XrLabel1_BeforePrint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs)
Handles XrLabel1.BeforePrint

    CType(sender, XRLabel).Tag = GetCurrentColumnValue("ID")

End Sub



Private Sub XrLabel1_HtmlItemCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.HtmlEventArgs) Handles XrLabel1.HtmlItemCreated

    e.ContentCell.InnerHtml =
String.Format("<a href=http://www.testarea.com/property.aspx?id={1}>{0}</a>", e.ContentCell.InnerText,
e.Data.Tag)
```

PS: I tried to convert it on this site http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

THE ORIGINAL CODE IS FOUND HERE http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/A1107.aspx

Comment: The only "challenge" would be having to subscribe to the event. The rest is just syntax.

Comment: your best bet was to google the function names: _BeforePrint and _HtmlItemCreated.  The DevExpress API doc has sample C# implmentations for those methods.  Ex. http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXRControl_BeforePrinttopic

Comment: There is a very good converting tool http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: @HW90, that conversion tool did not work as I posted in my original question

Comment: @ltiong_sh, i have been stuck with this for 2 days, you think i havent googled?, thats how i found the solution but now i am stuck with implementing in c#, did you see what i posted on my original post? those links were found googling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void XrLabel1_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
{
    ((XRLabel)sender).Tag = GetCurrentColumnValue("ID");
}

private void XrLabel1_HtmlItemCreated(object sender, DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.HtmlEventArgs e)
{
    e.ContentCell.InnerHtml = String.Format("<a href=http://www.testarea.com/property.aspx?id={1}>{0}</a>", e.ContentCell.InnerText, e.Data.Tag);
}
```

But the trick here is that you have to subscribe to the event somewhere, so you'll need this upon initialization:

```
XrLabel1.BeforePrint += XrLabel1_BeforePrint;
XrLabel1.HtmlItemCreate += XrLabel1_HtmlItemCreated;
```

Comment: I dont understand why it is not taking this line e.Data.Tag :(, it puts a red underline

Comment: Can you me show what the error says? It's one of the key things you need to show if you are asking about a specific error.

Comment: I found the issue, the dev express we have is a newer version I had to use e.Brick.Value. Thank you for the help, I was going to be stuck on this wouldnt been for your help :)

Comment: @Marlon I've had a same issue. I've created a new XtraReport object and subscribed to the HtmlItemCreated event but unfortunately its not getting raised. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

try this:
http://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/